# Columns from multiple files into single file using Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to load data from multiple csv files in a folder into a single csv file. All the files will be having  different schemas but will have a common primary key.

Sample structure of the files will be like

File1: PK,Col1,Col2,Col3

File2: PK,ColD,ColA,ColB,ColC

File3: PK,A,B,C

Final file structure should look something like this

PK,Col1,Col3,A,ColD,C,ColC

At the end, file will be saved in Parquet or Delta format.

Please suggest an approach on how to resolve this scenario using Spark,Scala

Adding some sample file contents for better understanding.

**File1**

emp_id | emp_name | job_name  | dep_id

68319 | KAYLING  | PRESIDENT |   1001

66928 | BLAZE    | MANAGER   |   3001

67832 | CLARE    | MANAGER   |   1001

65646 | JONAS    | MANAGER   |   2001

67858 | SCARLET  | ANALYST   |   2001

**File2**

emp_id | manager_id | hire_date

68319 |            | 1991-11-18

66928 |      68319 | 1991-05-01

67832 |      68319 | 1991-06-09

65646 |      68319 | 1991-04-02

67858 |      65646 | 1997-04-19

**File3**

emp_id | salary

68319 | 6000.00

66928 | 2750.00

67832 | 2550.00

65646 | 2957.00

67858 | 3100.00

**Final Result**

emp_id | emp_name | job_name  | manager_id | hire_date  | salary  | dep_id

68319 | KAYLING  | PRESIDENT |            | 1991-11-18 | 6000.00 |   1001

66928 | BLAZE    | MANAGER   |      68319 | 1991-05-01 | 2750.00 |   3001

67832 | CLARE    | MANAGER   |      68319 | 1991-06-09 | 2550.00 |   1001

65646 | JONAS    | MANAGER   |      68319 | 1991-04-02 | 2957.00 |   2001

67858 | SCARLET  | ANALYST   |      65646 | 1997-04-19 | 3100.00 |   2001

Answer (score 0):

1. Read all the files in one go
2. Select only those columns which you want in to a new DF.

```
val columns = List("PK","Col1","Col3","A","ColD","C","ColC")
val newDF = spark.read.csv("File1","File2","File3").select(columns.map(col):_*)
newDf.write.parquet("/parquet.file")
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @QuickSilver. But the dataframes always gets column names from the file with max number of columns. not able to get columns from files as they get appended.